# Loop variable inside object (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

how can i use variable for for loop inside object ?

e.g. :

enable all checkboxes with for

```
    Private Function AllEnabled(ByVal b As Boolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 15
        CheckBox(i).enabled = b
    Next
End Function
```

Sorry For Little Speak , & Thanks in Advance

Comment: What problem are you having with that code?  Looks okay to me.

Comment: checkbox(i) gives me error 'CheckBox' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: So that's your problem.  The `for` loop is fine.  You just need an array of checkboxes that you can iterate through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CheckBox(i)` syntax is classic VB6.  VB6 allowed you easily create control arrays directly in the form designer.  VB.NET does not share that same feature.  You could manually create your own array of check box controls in the code, but when using the designer, every control must be assigned its own unique name.  If you named them all sequentially, such as `CheckBox1`, `CheckBox2`, etc., then you could access them in a loop by name via the `Form.Controls` collection:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to 15
    Dim c As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i.ToString), CheckBox)
    c.Enabled = b
Next
```

Comment: @Zaid: if you need so many checkboxes, consider [CheckedListBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx).